# "Unexpected error during pre-commit" exception when persisting objects linked with bi-directionnal one-to-many owned relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, testng, datanucleus

### Context

I'm using a JDO's *bi-directionnal owned one-to-many relationship* between two objects (just like it is describe in the [App Engine's doc](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships?hl=en#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships)) in one of my cloud based java project.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class IndexPage implements Page {

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "index")
    @Order(extensions =
      @Extension(
        vendorName = "datanucleus",
        key = "list-ordering",
        value = "title asc"))
    private List<MotherCategoryPage> motherCategoryPages;

    (...)
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class MotherCategoryPage implements Page {
    private String title;

    @Persistent
    private IndexPage index;

    (...)
}
```

These objects are then stored into the appengine's datastore using the following very common JDO snippet of code:

```
public void persistPage(Page page) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    // persist a Page object
    pm.makePersistent(page);
    tx.commit();
    pm.close();
}
```

I have also implemented a (very simple) unit test using testNG where I instantiate both an IndexPage object and a MotherCategoryPage object and I persist them using the above method.

### The problem

Here's the problem. My code **runs quite well in production** (pages are well persisted both on local and on App Engine's servers), and **my unit test runs perfectly through Eclipse**.
But **the test failed when it's executed through maven !** (using the surefire plugin)

Here's the surefire report:

```
"Unexpected error during precommit"
org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:419)
org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOTransaction.commit(JDOTransaction.java:132)
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOTransaction.commit(DatastoreJDOTransaction.java:59)
com.mycompany.PageManager.persistPage(PageManager.java:102)
com.mycompany.pages.PageTest.putPagesIntoDb(PageTest.java:167)
com.mycompany.pages.PageTest.pageTest(PageTest.java:90)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:702)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:894)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1219)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:768)
org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1188)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1113)
org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1025)
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:177)
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:105)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)

NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.RunQuery().
at     com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:518)
at     com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:452)
at     com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:430)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:463)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:460)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/xml/XmlParser
at     com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCompositeIndexManager.getCompositeIndicesNode(LocalCompositeIndexManager.java:446)
at     com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCompositeIndexManager.manageIndexFile(LocalCompositeIndexManager.java:247)
at     com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCompositeIndexManager.processQuery(LocalCompositeIndexManager.java:200)
at     com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService$9.run(LocalDatastoreService.java:1068)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at     com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService.runQuery(LocalDatastoreService.java:1065)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at     com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:498)
... 10 more
```

In other words, the error happens when the changes are committed (line 6 of the above *persistPage* method) and is caused by:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/xml/XmlParser
```

Any idea of what's going on ? This is not a major issue, but I have to exclude this test from maven pre-commit to be able to push the project on my repo...

Comment: you post some exception but sadly ignore the real exception, which is nested. That and the log tell you what is going on

Comment: The real exception is nested indeed. I don't how to unwrapped the real datanucleus exception and that's the only logs that i have at my disposal. Maybe the version of datanucleus used by maven is different from the one used by appengine. I'm going to investigate.

Comment: e.printStackTrace() prints all nested exceptions. Logs are controllable by Log4J or java.util.logging config files (nothing to do with DataNucleus, they are standard libraries).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i've added the NestedThrowablesStackTrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with Maven it doesn't have all dependencies required by Mortbay's XMLParser (which is used by GAE indexing process - so nothing to do with persistence as such, but more AppEngine internals), and in other envs it uses some other XML parser, or has those required deps. So debug the jars in the CLASSPATH and what Maven includes for you and see the difference.

Comment: I've added the jetty dependency to the pom.xml (scope test) and everything works well know. Thanks !